# Emacs org-mode scheduling an item multiple times a day?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to schedule a task in emacs org-mode to show up multiple times during the day.

Edit: as an example suppose I want yo call my wife every 2 hours during the day.

Comment: Can you give a specific example for this?

Comment: There does not seem to be support for hourly repeaters (at least yet), see http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/30440

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the absence of hour/minute level repeaters, if the interval is not too small, you might add multiple timestamps for the hours, while using the other facilities for repeated items:

```
** Testentry
<2012-01-19 Do 10:00 +1w>
<2012-01-19 Do 12:00 +1w>
```

The resulting agenda view

```
Thursday   19 January 2012
  Calendar:   10:00...... Testentry
  Calendar:   12:00...... Testentry

[...]

Thursday   26 January 2012
               8:00...... ----------------
  Calendar:    9:45-10:00 XXXXXXXXXXXXXX                        :OFFICE:
               10:00...... 
  Calendar:   10:00...... Testentry
              10:00...... ----------------
  Calendar:   12:00...... Testentry
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This works, ...mostly, for me. I'm using timestamps with time ranges, like <2021-10-12 10:00-10:30> and <2021-10-12 13:30-14:00> and it puts the item in the agenda twice for the day as expected.  I do need to dig in a bit more because, although the second entry in the agenda is in the right spot, it shows the time to be a 10:00 (same as the first one, but again, it IS in the right slot on the agenda, so I can see that it's actually, in this case, not at 10:00)

Answer (score 8):

According to the Org Mode manual on [Repeated Tasks](http://orgmode.org/manual/Repeated-tasks.html) there is an hourly repeater:

> In the following example
>
> ```
> ** TODO Pay the rent
>    DEADLINE: <2005-10-01 Sat +1m>
> ```
>
> the `+1m` is a repeater; the intended interpretation is that the task
>   has a deadline on `<2005-10-01>` and repeats itself every (one) month
>   starting from that time. You can use yearly, monthly, weekly, daily
>   and **hourly** repeat cookies by using the `y`/`w`/`m`/`d`/**`h`** letters.

You may use something like that:

```
* TODO Call Wife
  DEADLINE: <2013-02-17 Sun 16:00 +2h>
```

Unfortunately, I've noticed that special repeater modifiers (`++` and `.+`) do not work properly for hourly repeaters. The manual says:

> ```
> ** TODO Call Father
>    DEADLINE: <2008-02-10 Sun ++1w>
>    Marking this DONE will shift the date by at least one week,
>    but also by as many weeks as it takes to get this date into
>    the future.  However, it stays on a Sunday, even if you called
>    and marked it done on Saturday.
> ```

Based on this, you would expect that marking an entry with an hourly repeater (such as the one above) `DONE` would "shift time by at least `n` hours but also as many hours as it takes to get this date into the future".

However, here's what I got after marking both entries `DONE`:

```
** TODO Call Father
   DEADLINE: <2013-03-03 Sun ++1w>
   - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2013-02-25 Mon 23:06]
   :PROPERTIES:
   :LAST_REPEAT: [2013-02-25 Mon 23:06]
   :END:

** TODO Call Wife
   DEADLINE: <2013-02-17 Sun 18:00 ++2h>
   - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2013-02-25 Mon 23:06]
   :PROPERTIES:
   :LAST_REPEAT: [2013-02-25 Mon 23:06]
   :END:
```

As you can see, the *time* in the second entry has shifted to `18:00`, but the *date* is still the same.

---

Concerning an approach for creating repeating items explicitly another feature could be useful. The manual says:

> An alternative to using a repeater is to create a number of copies of
>   a task subtree, with dates shifted in each copy. The command `C-c C-x c`
>   was created for this purpose, it is described in [Structure editing](http://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-editing.html).

But unfortunately, it doesn't work with hours.

---

Information in this post based on Org Mode version 7.9.3.e.

Comment: Org not handling hour-level repeaters correctly might have been a bug. Using Org 9.1.9 it seems to work as intended.

Comment: In Org 9.3 `.+` is broken for hours again. Clean Emacs with `2020-03-30 Mon 00:00 .+14h` repeats to `2020-03-30 Mon 14:00 .+14h` regardless of the current time.